# C++: get individual float values from a string line of floats

Tags: c++, string, parsing, floating-point

Suppose we have a string line:

`14.6527 39.5652 -344.226 -3.34672`

Let's call this string, `str_line`.

My question is, how can we parse this into a float array, `float data[4]`.

I tried using getline from stringstream but to no avail (see below for representation of my code). Any help would be appreciated :)

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  stringstream ss(str_line);
  ss.getline( str_line, 8, ' ' );
  data[i]=atof(ss);
}
```

Comment: What's this for? If it's part of a larger parser then you could use boost spirit qi; in which case your problem is solvable with a one liner.

Comment: I have a text file with lots of float values in it (each line contains 21 floats) and I want to put each float value into an array for later processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should declare `stringstream` object `ss` once, don't do it in a loop.

Then you have to only use the operator `>>` to extract floats from the stream.

```
stringstream ss(str_line);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  ss >> data[i];
}
```

If you're reading from a file, you can use a file stream like `ifstream` and read floats directly from it. The stream will ignore any whitespaces including newlines.

Comment: You should also test the status after the loop (and maybe verify that there's no more data left in `ss`).

Comment: @JamesKanze I guess it would be best if the OP used `ifstream` directly, implemented the appropriate error handling code, etc. OP can read a tutorial on handling streams to get it right. This simple question was about extracting 4 floats from a string that is known to contain them, so the answer is also limited.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `>>` operator on `stringstream`:

```
ss >> data[i];
```